# can't use the camera in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, android-camera, appcelerator-mobile

In my Titanium application I need to take pictures from camera, while invoking the camera action I am getting following error

```
Permission failure: android.permission.CAMERA from uid=10037 pid=407
E/CameraService(   34): Permission Denial: can't use the camera pid=407, uid=10037
```

I am invoking the camera by following code

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({
 .....
 .....
});
```

Where I have to add permission to use Camera? Anyone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Android applications, you need to add the following line to `manifest.xml` (outside of the `<application>` tag):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

---

In in which you're using Titanium, you can achieve the same effect by adding the line to `tiapp.xml` under the `<manifest>` tag, like this:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Comment: Did you mean tiapp.xml, where I can find the manifest.xml file.....I am a newbie to Titanium also Android

Comment: @joe: Updated my answer to give details more specific to Titanium.

Comment: way the @EdoDodo has shown is fine. Mostly titanium take care of all the permissions. If it don't than you just have to clean and build your project. Titanium will add all required permission automatically.